# Using single column table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, surrogate-key

I'm creating a database to store the events of mobile apps recovered from multiple sources. Problem is that rows from the event table don't have much meaning to the user as it's mostly a succession of integers. Forcing them to make multiple joins or multiple queries.

```
CREATE TABLE source (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value           string NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE application (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value           string NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE platform (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value           string NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE country (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    value           string NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE event (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    source_id       integer REFERENCES source(id),
    application_id  integer REFERENCES application(id),
    platform_id     integer REFERENCES platform(id),
    country_id      integer REFERENCES country(id),

    ...

    updated_at      date NOT NULL,
    value           decimal(100, 2) NOT NULL
);
```

I thought of directly using the value of the "secondary" tables as a primary key (as it's unique and not null) that I would reference in the event table. It would look like that:

```
CREATE TABLE source (
    value              string PRIMARY KEY
); 

CREATE TABLE application (
    value              string PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE platform (
    value              string PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE country (
    value              string PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE event (
    id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
    source          string REFERENCES source(value),
    application     string REFERENCES application(value),
    platform        string REFERENCES platform(value),
    country         string REFERENCES country(value),

    ...

    updated_at      date NOT NULL,
    value           decimal(100, 2) NOT NULL
);
```

I think it might also be good this way as I don't really see an added value at using a surrogate key in this situation. Also prevents me from using views which might have slower performances as it executes a query every time I use the view in a query.

What do you think of this option ?

Comment: If the `value` columns in your `source`, `platform`, `application`, and `country` tables satisfy the criteria for a primary key (not null, unique, and unchanging) then I like the second design better.

Comment: The downside of the second approach is that you will duplicate the text values in `event` table. If the values are long, it will take up much space, which can be avoided if you were using integer keys.

Comment: If the strings are codes then use them as keys. Simple beats complex, if it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"real" systems usually use surrogate keys.  There are multiple reasons why:

- Integers are more efficient for indexes, because they are fixed length.
- Integers are more efficient for foreign key references, because they are only four bytes (strings are often larger).
- String values may change and then referring tables need to be updated.
- Auto generated primary keys contain other information, such as the order of insertion.
- End users do not directly access tables.  If such functionality is needed, then views are fine.

There is nothing *per se* wrong with using strings.  But in practice, they are not used for this purpose.